# Calculating Response Rates in R

Tags: r

I have a data table in R, for example:

[image]

The id column is a unique customerid. What I would like to do is calculate a response rate column by the segment factor.

How would I perform a function such as `count(unique paymentid)/count(unique id)` exlcuding the NAs in the paymentid?

I would like my resulting table to look like:

[image]

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There may be a more elegant way to do this, but here's one option with (a slightly outdated version of) `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
library(scales)
##
setDT(Df)
##
Df2 <- Df[
  ,list(
    NumberSent=.N,
   NumberResponded=length(
     unique(na.omit(paymentid)))),
  by=segment][,ResponseRate:=percent(
    NumberResponded/NumberSent)]
##
R> Df2
   segment NumberSent NumberResponded ResponseRate
1:       Y          2               1        50.0%
2:       R          2               2       100.0%
3:       B          3               2        66.7%
```

where the package `scales` was just for the function `percent`.

---

**Data:**

```
Df <- data.frame(
  id=1:7,
  segment=rep(c("Y","R","B"),c(2,2,3)),
  paymentamount=c(10,NA,20,15,12,13,NA),
  paymentid=c(11,NA,12,13,14,15,NA))
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to do this. Here's an approach using `by`, and one using `dplyr`:

```
d <- data.frame(segment=c('Y', 'Y', 'R', 'R', 'B', 'B', 'B'),
                paymentamount=c(10, NA, 20, 15, 12, 13, NA))
```

**by**

```
do.call(rbind, 
        by(d$paymentamount, d$segment, function(x) {
          sent <- length(x)
          responded <- sum(!is.na(x))
          cbind.data.frame(sent, responded, rate=round(responded/sent*100))
        }))

#   sent responded rate
# B    3         2   67
# R    2         2  100
# Y    2         1   50
```

**dplyr**

```
library(dplyr)
d %>% group_by(segment) %>%
  summarise(sent=length(paymentamount), 
            responded=sum(!is.na(paymentamount)),
            rate=round(responded/sent*100, 2))

# Source: local data frame [3 x 4]
# 
#   segment sent responded   rate
# 1       B    3         2  66.67
# 2       R    2         2 100.00
# 3       Y    2         1  50.00
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I used dplyr

```
d <- data.frame(segment=c('Y', 'Y', 'R', 'R', 'B', 'B', 'B'), paymentamount=c(10, NA, 20, 15, 12, 13, NA))

require(dplyr)

x <- d %>%
  group_by(segment) %>%
  summarize(NumberSent = n(), NumberResponded = sum(!is.na(paymentamount)), 
    ResponseRate = paste(round(100*(NumberResponded/NumberSent),0),"%", sep="") ) %>%
  arrange(desc(segment))
```